# Does Istio provide a dashboard similar to Kubernetes (yet)?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Does [Istio](https://istio.io/) have a dashboard similar to https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard yet?

Comment: No, Istio is not providing any dashboard as of now, as like kubernetes. But, metrics and monitoring tools ships with Istio like Promethus, Grafana and Zipkin from where you could visualize all the objects in the Istio system.

Comment: That's not expressly true -- check this out https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/using-istio-dashboard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively new project called Kiali aims to provide a UI to observe Istio service mesh.

https://github.com/kiali/kiali

Comment: Check what Istio project says about Kiali: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/
It looks like Kiali is the supported version for observing applications running on the mesh. kiali.io might be useful to see some more details

Answer (score 2):

While it's not quite the same as the Kubernetes dashboard, Istio does come bundled with Grafana, which provides a UI for visualizing Istio metrics (via Prometheus).

See Istio's documentation for how to access: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/using-istio-dashboard/

TL;DR, run this command: `kubectl -n istio-system port-forward $(kubectl -n istio-system get pod -l app=grafana -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') 3000:3000`

then navigate here for the dashboard: http://localhost:3000/dashboard/db/istio-mesh-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

yes  it has kiali dashboard.you can see istio configurations over there and  also  visualize istio mesh.

you can refer the below official documentation for same.

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/